Isnt there any option in Youtube Api to get live poll data and result for live streams?
I was looking for any way to get the result of ongoing poll in live stream and get updates about it,
But I haven't got in the YouTube Api docs.
I don't want to try to extract or build chrome extension for it.
As it may not be ethically allowed by YouTube (I am not sure, just guess).
If there isn't any another way, we will have no other way than to extract the web pages.
And Secondary Question
If anyone has worked with Youtube Api.
Does YouTube exceed our limit easily or will it take longer time and have rejections for it?
[Regarding the process to increase the limit of  10000 quota on free use of api.]

What do you mean by Does YouTube exceed our limit easily or will it take longer time and have rejections for it?? Web-scraping seems to be the only solution, I opened an issue for this purpose in my web-scraping open-source API. I will try to work on it when I'll have a minute.

@BenjaminLoison Ohh Sorry.There is quota limit for free use of api of 10000.And there is form to exceed the limit which requires to mention details about your projects.So I was asking is that process easy or too complex if any one have done in the past.Ya I think I should have not posted here, it seems little off topic to main question

@BenjaminLoison Thanks for taking interest and opening a issue.I would connect over github issue.

One more time YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide a basic feature.
I recommend you to try out my open-source YouTube operational API. Indeed by fetching https://yt.lemnoslife.com/lives?part=poll&id=VIDEO_ID, you will get the poll you are looking for in item["poll"].
Here is an example response:
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
    "etag": "NotImplemented",
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "etag": "NotImplemented",
            "id": "VIDEO_ID",
            "poll": {
                "question": "Question",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "text": "First choice",
                        "voteRatio": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "Second choice",
                        "voteRatio": 0
                    }
                ],
                "channelName": "Benjamin Loison",
                "timestamp": "2\u00a0min ago",
                "totalVotes": 2,
                "channelThumbnails": [
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yt4.ggpht.com\/ijUcEdCQW8vxf5pkiKVANsW3rCVTjXPbmtE2unfplLJUcmYYzFofB8ZPV-1d-NUpFfE44nzSfQ=s32-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                        "width": 32,
                        "height": 32
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "https:\/\/yt4.ggpht.com\/ijUcEdCQW8vxf5pkiKVANsW3rCVTjXPbmtE2unfplLJUcmYYzFofB8ZPV-1d-NUpFfE44nzSfQ=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
                        "width": 64,
                        "height": 64
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}


Poll API was added in late 2024. Check it out here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages
